# Infinite loop Kafka Consumer

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm testing some basic Kafka feature, I have basics `zookeeper/kafka` servers running on a Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS virtual machine. And I use the `kafka-node` module.

This script should be waiting for new message to arrive in order to consume it.
But it is stuck in an infinite loop as soon as I launch it.

I can't find where it comes from,

```
"use strict"
require('dotenv').config();
var kafka = require('kafka-node');

const client = new kafka.Client("localhost:2181");
var topics = [{
  topic: 'stuff',
  offset: 0
}];
var options = {
  autoCommit: false
}
const HLConsumer = new kafka.HighLevelConsumer(client, topics, options);

HLConsumer.on('message', function(message) {
  console.log(message);
});

HLConsumer.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('error', err);
});

HLConsumer.on('offsetOutOfRange', function(err) {
  console.log('offsetOutOfRange:', err);
})
```

Have a nice day every one, and thanks

Edit 1 :

I updated as requested `autoCommit` to `true` and still have to problem.
Here is a cheap gif of the issues, in fact it loop through every offset and then read 10/15 message with an offset of 0 then restart looping on every offset of the topic
[image: gif loop]

Comment: How does it keep looping? Do you keep receiving the same message? Are there any errors in your log?

Comment: You have set `autoCommit: false` so you will have to commit the offset manually. Can you please set it to `true` to verify that this part works. Do you have any specific requirements since you have set it to `false`? FYI: `HighLevelConsumer` is deprecated. I have very limited knowledge of node.js

Comment: Thanks for he answer I edited the post

Comment: Sadly a GIF wont help. It goes too fast to see what its posting. You will have to check the kafka debug log too how the messages are processed.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem before, the solution was update kafka-node.

Answer (score -2):

I found what was causing this : 
I used to declare my consumer like that

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node');
...
var consumer = new kafka.Consumer(client, topics, options);
```

but the good way to do it is :

```
var kafkaConsumer = require('kafka-node').Consumer;
...
var consumer = new kafkaConsumer(client, topics, options);
```

Comment: NeitoFR how could that have resolved the issue? Both seem to be functionally equivalent, are you sure it wasn't something else you changed which resolved it?

Comment: I'm asking that myself too. but that seems to be all... it was the only thing different in the code